# Running Tomcat with JRockit

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, jrockit

I have installed jrockit in my Ubuntu 11.10 and I would to configure Tomcat7 to run with jrockit in order to getting rid of PermGen (OutOfMemorry).

But I don't know how configure Tomcat to run wirh JRockit

Please , any idea ?!!

Comment: That's Fine . I resolved the problem by right-clicking on tomcat server in Netbeans>properties>Platforme> {JRockit-Home}

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit `/etc/default/tomcat7`.

Change `JAVA_HOME` to point to to your JRockit installation.

Change `JAVA_OPTS` to remove the `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` flag (which doesn't work with JRockit).

Then restart tomcat with "`sudo service tomcat7 restart`".

Answer (score 0):

Running Tomcat with JRockit and enabling monitoring with Mission Control

In catalina.bat add after initial comments

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\JRockit\Java\jrockit-jdk1.6.0_20-R28.1.0-4.0.1
set JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 
    -Xmanagement:ssl=false, authenticate=false, port=7091 %JAVA_OPTS%
```

Then run:
catalina run

I got this answer from this [blog](http://sdoulger.blogspot.in/2011/06/running-tomcat-with-jrockit-and.html)